# From a linguistic point of view - can the order of steps in 手順 be changed?

Tags: meaning

I was present at a company meeting in which quite a few Japanese people started to seriously consider if the order of things prescribed in 手順書 can be freely changed. Namely 手順の順番を変えるのは大丈夫か -like questions.

For me as a foreigner the 順 determines the order of things and I listened in consternation. Most dictionaries define 手順 as 順序 or 段取り<sup>[*](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86-575858)</sup>. In either case they sound to me like following a path in chronological / planned order.

Doesn't the etymology limit the meaning here to the steps performed in a predetermined order? From a linguistic point of view doesn't 手順 determine the order of things?

If no, how shall the 順 part be interpreted?

Comment: jisho.org has 手順書 as "process document (computer term)".  A goal is to specify dependencies between processes (there is a strong connection between inter-dependence and ordering).

Comment: I think your question is more subjective and situational rather than Japanese-specific. Sure the order of operations on any kind of process can be changed (in any language), as long as it doesn't create conflicting dependencies or ruin the process as a whole. If it achieves the result in a better/more efficient way, then I don't see a problem. You would probably need to share the specific steps in order to get a better answer here.

Comment: @starmandeluxe But I am not asking about particular situation, I am asking about how the word is built.

Comment: @macraf The word is built ("means") the same as the English version as far as I am aware. It means an ordered set of steps. But even with this definition, that doesn't mean it can't or shouldn't be changed.

Comment: If you have an answer to my question, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a difference between "what should be done" and "what the word implies it is doing". 手順 simply means a process or protocol and can be implied to be an ordered set of steps, in the same manner as the English terms "operational manual" or "step-by-step guide" would be. Now just because this is the meaning doesn't imply that the order is always correct or the best order by default. I think that's up to the opinions of whoever created/has to deal with this process.

Comment: Could you provide some reference for the claim "*手順 simply means a process or protocol and can be implied to be an ordered set of steps*"? This is the crux of my question.

Comment: From a linguistic point of view an English phrase "numbered list" implies numbers being used. It doesn't prevent Microsoft from putting "A) B) C)" as a selection in "numbered list"-menu in Word. I'm not asking about potential interpretations (I already know they are possible from the experience I described), but how the word 手順 is built.

Comment: If a dictionary definition was all you were looking for, why even post this question? You can find the definition in any dictionary: http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/151481/meaning/m0u/

Comment: If you click on the asterisk in the question, your browser will open `kotobank.jp`. Are you suggesting `dictionary.goo.ne.jp` answers my question, while the one I cited to support it does not?

Comment: Nope, I am reaffirming that the definition is what you are suggesting, but just as in English, these "steps" can be manually overridden.

Comment: But that's not my question! I came up with a new example what I'm asking about and what I am not. What's the point of reaffirming the definition used in my question? You stubbornly try to turn discussion into confirming the possibility of acting in a certain way. Yes, "A) B) C)"-numbered list is also possible, so does it prove A is a number from a linguistic point of view?

Comment: Calm down, you're thinking too hard. The answer is No. It's an abstract freeform procedure. It can be ordered or not.

Comment: I am not asking if it can be ordered or not. There are already three comments in which I stated that. This one is fourth.

Comment: Then please update your question to reflect these new inquiries. I answered the original question.

Comment: I feel no need to update the question, because you refused to support your only claim that addresses the question: "*手順 simply means a process or protocol and can be implied to be an ordered set of steps*".

Comment: I already supported it yet you refuse to accept the citations. Have a nice day.

Comment: But you supported it with a duplicate of the material that I included to support my question. Why do you think I asked the question in the first place? So that someone will include their own opinion and quote the resource I included claiming it proves it? Or maybe I wanted to learn something that I could not figure out myself?